# Why isn't this php code allowing me to connect to my database?

Tags: php, database, wamp

I'm using a WAMP server and on it I created a database and a table. All the names are correct and the user has full access to everything. When I run the code, it prints out "Unable to select database". Thanks.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){  
        print_r ($_POST["nutrient"]);
}




session_start();

//establish connection
$server = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$database = "gainlife_cavin";
$table = "cavintable"; 


//connect PHP script to database
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $db_username, $db_password, $database);


//select database to use
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

//$query = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES("")"
//mysql_query($query)

mysql_close();



?>

<body>
</form>
```

Comment: you are using `mysqli_connect` , eventually 4th parameter is a `$database` which selects current database. Also you are using `mysqli_connect` which is a `mysqli_*` wrapper and using `mysql_select_db` which is a `mysql` wrapper. Remove this

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following.

```
<?php
//establish connection
$server = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$database = "gainlife_cavin";
$table = "cavintable"; 

    //connect PHP script to database
    $connection =mysqli_connect("$server","$db_username","$db_password","$database");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    //Your query here

    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use simple code 1 line. here is my code that i'm using.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You went from MySQLI to not using MySQLI in selecting the database as well as the rest of your code.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. I have change `mysqli_connect` to `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` variable.

```
//connect PHP script to database
$connection = mysql_connect($server, $db_username, $db_password, $database);


//select database to use
$select  = mysql_select_db($connection) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

Comment: A very very wrong approach. Why would you encourage someone to go back and use a deprecated API?